# How to pass events using props from one component to another in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am a beginner learning React JS. I am having a React Bootstrap table, where I can select and compare products using "Compare" and "Clear" Buttons. As I will be using Button multiple times through out my project, I wanted to have a "Button" Component, where I can pass the eventHandling and Button text through props. Can any one please help me?

What I have right now -

Container Component:

```
<button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Compare</button>
<button onClick={this.onClearClick}>Clear</button>
```

What I wanted to do -

Container Component:

```
<Button onClick={this.onButtonClick} text="Compare"/>
<Button onClick={this.onClearClick} text="Clear"/>
```

Button Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = (props) => {
    return (

        <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.text}</button>
    );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
    message : 'Click Me!'
};

export default Button ;
```

Full code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/pk964xy5w0

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Do you want use Button component everywhere by passing the event? Where did you got stuck?

Comment: what you are doing looks like its working and you are handling it right so far...so yes what is the problem you inquiring about ??

Comment: Where do you define the button component (button in lower case)? First thing you need is to use a name starting with a capital letter, then you need to define it...

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine. Sorry for the post.